# react native background fetch for delivery app

Tags: react-native, expo, headless

I am making delivery boy app in react native expo so I need help that when new order placed (i have an api which returns true or false ) when true  app should vibrate and play sound  or notification in the background or when app is closed so how to do

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have done in kotlin it works by background intent i have to do in react native

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's ideal to implement this with normal HTTP requests, you need to research implementing these functionalities on the backend with either websockets or push notifications, read:

- [Implementing Expo Push Notificaitons](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/)
- [Using Firebase Cloud Messaging (RN)](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage)
- [Using Firebase Cloud Messaging (Backend)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server)
- [Websockets in React Native](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-implement-websockets-in-react-native/)